# The uniform convergence of $\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-ax^2}x^{2n}\mathrm{d}x \quad w.r.t \ a$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, improper-integrals, uniform-convergence

> For fixed $n\in \mathbb{N}$, study the uniform convergence of
> $$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-ax^2}x^{2n}\mathrm{d}x  \quad w.r.t \ a\in(0,\infty)$$.

Actually I want to compute the integral by differentiating
$$
\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-ax^2}\mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{a}},
$$
but we need to prove $$\int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-ax^2}x^{2n+2}\mathrm{d}x $$
converges uniformly w.r.t $a>0$. Then the procedure is legal. The Weierstrass, Dirichlet and Abel criterion all seem do not work.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What is converging to what?

Comment: easy recurrence from integration by parts

Comment: Questions about uniform convergence of improper integrals tend to be misunderstood here and are confused with valuation.  The notion of uniform convergence for an improper integral $\int_0^\infty f(x,a) \, dx$ pertains to the convergence $\lim_{c \to \infty} \int_0^c f(x,a) \, dx$ and uniformity with respect to the parameter $a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The convergence of the improper integral is uniform for $a$ in any interval $[A,\infty)$ where $A > 0$.

This follows from the Weierstrass M-test since $|e^{-ax^2}x^{2n}| \leqslant e^{-Ax^2}x^{2n}$ for all $a \geqslant A$ and for any fixed $n$ the improper integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-Ax^2}x^{2n} \, dx$ converges.

However, for any $c > 0$ and $a_c = 1/c^2 \in (0,\infty)$,

$$\sup_{a \in (0,\infty)}\left|\int_c^{\infty} e^{-ax^2}x^{2n} \, dx\right| \geqslant \sup_{a \in (0,\infty)}\int_c^{2c} e^{-ax^2}x^{2n} \, dx\geqslant \sup_{a \in (0,\infty)}c \cdot e^{-a (2c)^2} c^{2n}\geqslant  e^{-4a_c c^2} c^{2n+1}\\ = e^{-4}c^{2n+1} \underset{c \to \infty}\longrightarrow \infty$$

Thus, the improper integral fails to converge uniformly (with respect to $a$) on $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Yup. It may be useful to explicitly state that that doesn't matter much, *locally uniform* convergence is sufficient here (and in most cases one encounters).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$I_n=\int_0^\infty {e}^{-ax^2}x^{2n}\,dx$$
$$x=\sqrt t \implies I_n= \frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty e^{-a t} t^{n-\frac{1}{2}}\,dt=\frac{1}{2} a^{-(n+\frac{1}{2})} \Gamma \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$